# wildcards in cloudant query json

Tags: wildcard, cloudant

I have created a cloudant Query index --json, for a field in a cloudant DB. But I am not able to use the wildcards in the selector of the cloudant query.
ex:
priority field can take the values a,b,c,d,e,f...z
In the selector below I am trying to retrieve all the records in the DB and then sort it on priority itself.. but when I use the wildcards, it is not returning results at all.

```
{
  "selector": {
    "priority":"*"
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "priority": "asc"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please tell me which wildcard need to be used to retrieve all the docs

Answer (score 2):

you may want to try using the **$regex** selector

```
{
  "selector": {
    "_id": {
      "$gt": 0
    },
    "priority": {
      "$regex": ".*"
    },
    "sort": [
      {
        "priority": "asc"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

additional information about **$regex** can be found here:

https://docs.cloudant.com/cloudant_query.html#creating-selector-expressions